# Debugging a function that tries to merge two strings but sometimes does not return

Tags: python, python-3.x, return

The function is supposed to return True if the parameter s can be formed solely from the parameters part1 and part2, and returns False otherwise. My function works when it is supposed to return True, but when False, it doesn't return anything at all.

```
def is_merge(s, part1, part2):
  list = []
  v1 = 0
  v2 = 0
  i = 0
  while i < len(s):
      if v1 < len(part1) and s[i] == part1[v1]  :
          list.append(s[i])
          i += 1
          v1 += 1
      elif v2 < len(part2) and s[i] == part2[v2] :
          list.append(s[i])
          i += 1
          v2 += 1
  list = ''.join(list)
  if list == s:
      return True
  else:
      return False

right = (is_merge('codewars', 'cdw', 'oears'))
wrong = (is_merge('codewarse', 'cdw', 'oears'))

if right == True:
  print("true")

if wrong == False:
  print("false")
```

Comment: In the second case, neither `if` nor `elif` condition is satisfied, so `i` is not incremented and the while loop runs forever.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "can be formed solely from the parameters part1 and part2". Do you mean string `s` can be formed by combining and rearranging the letters in `part1` and `part2`? What about repeated letters?